# comma separated values (CSV) to an array

Tags: t-sql, csv, sql-server-2008-r2

```
declare @inputString nvarchar(20) = 'a,bc,def,ghij'
declare @i int = 1
declare @j int = 0
declare @character nvarchar(1) 
while(@i <= LEN(@inputString))
begin
set @character =  SUBSTRING(@inputstring,@i,1)
if (@character = ',')
begin
substring(@inputstring,@i,1)=' ' --it is showing an error near substring here
end
set @i = @i + 1
end
```

Kindly help me rectify this error , can't we use `substring` on the left hand side of the expression?

I am trying to get all the commas and replace them with a space. Also, how can I convert the space separates values to an array?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this `substring(@inputstring,@i,1)=' '`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `REPLACE` to replace the commas

```
declare @inputString nvarchar(20) = 'a,bc,def,ghij';
set @inputString = REPLACE(@inputString, ',', ' ')
select @inputString
```

Also you can return the space separate values in a table format using the below function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit](@text Nvarchar(4000), @delimiter Nvarchar(20))  
RETURNS @Strings TABLE  
(      
   --position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
   Splvalue Nvarchar(Max)     
)  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @index int   
SET @index = -1   
WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)   
BEGIN    
SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)    
IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)    
  BEGIN     
    INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)  
      BREAK    
  END    
IF (@index >= 1)    
  BEGIN     
if (@index - 1) = 0  
 INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (Null)  
else     
 INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))     
SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))    
  END    
ELSE   
  SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))   
END  
RETURN  
END
```

And use it to get the output in table format

```
select * from dbo.FnSplit(@inputString,' ')
```